# express-handlebars cant find dir or file

Tags: node.js, express, express-handlebars

okey so im trying to get handlebars to workand so ive been following this youtube guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SfQFoMOd_ng

and my problem is that the code on row 15 gets an error:

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\9826skma\Desktop\Lol stats\playground\test handlebars\views\layouts\main.handlebars'

[server.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5paB.png)

ive used

npm i express --save, npm i express-handlebars --save in powershell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your folder is called `layout`, but the code is looking for `layouts`.

Comment: my god..., thx, you dont know how long ive been stuck with this xd

Comment: Glad to help. ;)

Answer (score 6):

You can also add defaultLayout: null. So for example ...

```
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
    extname: '.hbs',
    defaultLayout: null
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
extname: '.hbs',
defaultLayout: 'main',
partialsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'views/partials'),
layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'views/layouts')


 }));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');

app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));
```

tried the above code and worked smoothly

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake, I had written this with a camelcase-

```
extName: '.hbs'
```

instead of all lowercase-

```
extname: '.hbs'
```